# How to match a relative IRI of a Subject in an RDF triple in SPARQL query language?

Tags: xml, sparql, rdf, raptor2, rasqal

I am trying to use `SPARQL` to match an IRI that is relative to the base. Here's an example snippet of rdf-xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:bqbiol="http://biomodels.net/biology-qualifiers/"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xml:base="base-uri.rdf">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="metaid_1">
    <bqbiol:is rdf:resource="https://identifiers.org/uniprot/P0DP23"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I want to match this triple based on the subject `rdf:about="metaid_1"`. If I run the following sparql query:

```
// query 1


SELECT ?x ?y ?z
WHERE {
  ?x ?y ?z
}
```

The result is:

```
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rs:      <http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/tests/result-set#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

[]    rdf:type      rs:ResultSet ;
      rs:resultVariable  "x" ;
      rs:resultVariable  "y" ;
      rs:resultVariable  "z" ;
      rs:solution   [ rs:binding    [ rs:variable   "x" ;
                                      rs:value      <metaid_1>
                                    ] ; 
                      rs:binding    [ rs:variable   "y" ;
                                      rs:value      <http://biomodels.net/biology-qualifiers/is>
                                    ] ; 
                      rs:binding    [ rs:variable   "z" ;
                                      rs:value      <https://identifiers.org/uniprot/P0DP23>
                                    ] 
      ] .
```

But when I run any of the following, I get an empty result:

```
// query 2
SELECT ?y ?z
WHERE {
  <metaid_1> ?y ?z
}

// query 3
SELECT ?y ?z
WHERE {
  <base-uri.rdf#metaid_1> ?y ?z
}


// query 4
SELECT ?y ?z
WHERE {
  <base-uri.rdf/metaid_1> ?y ?z
}
```

Could anybody suggest an alternative query for matching triples based on the relative `metaid_1` iri?

## edit - response to comments

I forgot to mention that I did try using `BASE` like so:

```
// query 5
SELECT ?y ?z
WHERE {
  <BASE/metaid_1> ?y ?z
}
```

and a few variants, but not was suggested in the comment which was:

```
// query 6
BASE <base-uri.rdf>
SELECT ?y ?z
WHERE {
  <metaid_1> ?y ?z
}
```

Which also returns an empty set of results.

## edit 2 - response to more comments

@uninformedUser is correct in that I was going for local iri's because these subjects are essentially metaid attributes on xml elements for local xml strings.
I suppose when the package I'm writing is used online they would become `https://`, but for now they are just strings created for testing.

I have tried changing the `xml:base` to `file:///mnt/d/libsemsim/tests/base-uri.rdf` so now the xml snippet reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:bqbiol="http://biomodels.net/biology-qualifiers/"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xml:base="file:///mnt/d/libsemsim/tests/base-uri.rdf">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="metaid_1">
    <bqbiol:is rdf:resource="https://identifiers.org/uniprot/P0DP23"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

And the query:

```
BASE <file:///mnt/d/libsemsim/tests/base-uri.rdf> 
SELECT ?y ?z
WHERE {
  <metaid_1> ?y ?z
}
```

But still my result set is empty. I'm wondering whether the problem is that I'm querying the `rdf` `model` itself, which is a central object in the [librdf package](http://librdf.org/) and not necessarily a serialized representation of the xml as I've been showing here.

Comment: shouldn't you use `BASE` in the SPARQL query then? Like `BASE <base-uri.rdf> SELECT ?y ?z
WHERE {
  <metaid_1> ?y ?z
}`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either (i've updated the question).

Comment: hm, the problem that I see is that `xml:base="base-uri.rdf"` is not a proper URI, thus, it resolves to a document local URI I think. you can see that it works with `BASE` keyword once the data uses `xml:base="http://base-uri.rdf"` which then resolves to `http://base-uri.rdf/metaid_1`

Comment: so, once you load your current document, it will resolve to `file:///path_to_local_file/metaid_1` something that your SPARQL client isn't aware of indeed, because just doing `<metaid_1>` in the query can only resolve to the local URI of your SPARQL service, e.g. `http://uri_to_SPARQL_service/metaid_1`

Comment: @UninformedUser, Really appreciate the help, but so far I've still not been able to get a query to return results using either `https` or `file//` in front of the uri.

Comment: well, I can't help further here I guess because data and query are correct and produce the expected result when using Apache Jena (which I tried on my computer)